# How to set up SnappyData cluster with any host other than localhost?

Tags: gemfire, snappydata

When I set up the snappydata cluster with all locators, services and leads running in the same machine and the host names are specified as "localhost" - then I can see the service comes up.
With the same set up when I replace localhost with the actual host name, then it continuously asks for ssh login and after giving valid password also I don't see any error and the service doesn't come up.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think you are using `sbin/snappy-start-all.sh` to launch your cluster, which needs [passwordless ssh enabled](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/reference/misc/passwordless_ssh/) on the hosts.

Have you gone through [instructions mentioned here](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/install/install_on_premise/#multi-host-installation)?

If it didn't help, will need more details like your conf files (locators, servers and leads) and the commands executed to start the cluster and error messages you see, to be able to help you better.